What does syntax of the form `template <…> some_type(…) -> some_type<…>` mean?
Reading a library and trying to understand how it works. But I don't understand the following syntax:
template<typename T>
struct Data
{
    T value;
};

// Don't understand what is happening here. 
template<typename T>
Data(T) -> Data<T>;


That looks like a user-defined deduction guide.
